# AutoML Vision: Dataset import takes long time and fails eventually

Tags: google-cloud-automl

I am currently trying to import a single-label dataset that contains ~7300 images. I use a single CSV file in the following format to create the dataset from (paths shortened):

```
gs://its-2018-40128940-automl-vis-vcm/[...].jpg,CAT_00
gs://its-2018-40128940-automl-vis-vcm/[...].jpg,CAT_00
gs://its-2018-40128940-automl-vis-vcm/[...].jpg,CAT_00
[...]
```

However, the import process failed after processing for over 7 hours (which I find unusually long based on previous experience) with the following error:

```
File unreadable or invalid gs://[...]
```

The strange thing is: The files were there and I was able to download and view them on my machine. And once I removed all entries from the CSV except the two "unreadable or invalid" ones and imported this CSV file (same bucket), it worked like a charm and took just a few seconds.

Another dataset with 500 other images caused the same strange behavior.

I have imported and trained a few AutoML Vision models before and I can't figure out what is going wrong this time. Any ideas or debugging tips appreciated. The GCP project is "its-2018-40128940-automl-vis".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

File unreadable or invalid is returned when a file either cannot be accessed from GCS (cannot be read due to file size or permissions) or when the file format is considered invalid. For example image is in different format than the extension used or in format that is not supported by [image service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/images/#image-formats).

When there are errors the pipeline may be slow because currently it does re-tries with exponential backoff. It tries to detect non-retry-able errors and fail fast - but errs on the re-try if unsure side.

It would be best if you could ensure the images are in the right format - for example by re-converting the images into one of the supported formats. 
Depending on your platform there are tools to do that.

Answer (score 0):

When I check a file via uploaded in the UI of GCP Storage

[image]

To match this one we have to upload the file in following configurations,

```
storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(`./${csv_file}`, {
    // Support for HTTP requests made with `Accept-Encoding: gzip`
    destination: `csv/${csv_file}`,
    gzip: false,
    metadata: {

    },
});
```